# Sphinx Searchd long to restart

Tags: sphinx, binlog

we've been using Sphinx (2.0.4) for about 4 years, but recently (like a month ago), searches started having downtimes once an hour.

We have a big update of all the data during the night, which doesn't cause any problem. We then have an indexation running once at the beginning of every hour, which generally add 20 to 30 rows to the index.

So there is the cronjob running once every hour:

```
#!/bin/bash

date1=`date`
echo "$date1 : Starting indexation..." >> /cyber/indexer-new.log

/usr/local/bin/indexer -c /etc/sphinx.conf newCompanies --noprogress --rotate
date1=`date`
echo "$date1 : Indexation ended" >> /cyber/indexer-new.log

date1=`date`
echo "$date1 : Restart searchd" >> /cyber/indexer-new.log

/usr/local/bin/searchd -c /etc/sphinx.conf --stopwait
exitCode=`echo $?`
echo "Exit code (--stopwait) : $exitCode" >> /cyber/indexer-new.log

/usr/local/bin/searchd -c /etc/sphinx.conf
exitCode=`echo $?`
echo "Exit code (restart sphinx) : $exitCode" >> /cyber/indexer-new.log

date1=`date`
echo "$date1 : searchd restarted.." >> /cyber/indexer-new.log

exit 0
```

The result use to be something like this (searchd.log) but with 70000 rows of binlog replay (1560 binlog files) that seem to be empty:

```
[Wed May 18 10:01:14.541 2016] [11983] rotating indices (seamless=1)
[Wed May 18 10:01:14.545 2016] [11983] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed May 18 10:01:16.953 2016] [11983] shutdown complete
[Wed May 18 10:01:16.954 2016] [11982] Child process 11983 has been finished, exit code 0. Watchdog finishes also. Good bye!
[Wed May 18 10:01:16.957 2016] [13505] Child process 13506 has been forked
[Wed May 18 10:01:16.958 2016] [13506] listening on all interfaces, port=9312
[Wed May 18 10:01:16.958 2016] [13506] listening on all interfaces, port=9306
[Wed May 18 10:01:36.131 2016] [13506] rotating index 'newCompanies': success
[Wed May 18 10:01:36.133 2016] [13506] binlog: replaying log /usr/local/var/data/binlog.001
[Wed May 18 10:01:36.133 2016] [13506] binlog: replay stats: 0 rows in 0 commits; 0 updates; 0 indexes
```

But it now looks like this

```
[Sun Jul 31 10:00:57.285 2016] [28792] rotating indices (seamless=1)
[Sun Jul 31 10:00:57.292 2016] [28792] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jul 31 10:00:57.294 2016] [28792] rotating index 'newCompanies': started
[Sun Jul 31 10:00:57.404 2016] [28792] rotating index 'newCompanies': success
[Sun Jul 31 10:00:57.404 2016] [28792] rotating index: all indexes done
[Sun Jul 31 10:01:00.166 2016] [28792] shutdown complete
[Sun Jul 31 10:01:00.167 2016] [28791] Child process 28792 has been finished, exit code 0. Watchdog finishes also. Good bye!
[Sun Jul 31 10:01:00.175 2016] [29781] Child process 29782 has been forked
[Sun Jul 31 10:01:00.175 2016] [29782] listening on all interfaces, port=9312
[Sun Jul 31 10:01:00.175 2016] [29782] listening on all interfaces, port=9306
[Sun Jul 31 10:03:01.946 2016] [29782] binlog: replaying log /usr/local/var/data/binlog.001
[Sun Jul 31 10:03:01.953 2016] [29782] binlog: replay stats: 0 rows in 0 commits; 0 updates; 0 indexes
[Sun Jul 31 10:03:01.953 2016] [29782] binlog: finished replaying /usr/local/var/data/binlog.001; 0.0 MB in 0.000 sec
```

Notice the 2 minutes gap.

The cronjob log looks like this:

```
Mon Aug  1 11:00:01 EDT 2016 : Starting indexation...
Mon Aug  1 11:01:17 EDT 2016 : Indexation ended
Mon Aug  1 11:01:17 EDT 2016 : Restart searchd
Exit code (--stopwait) : 0
Exit code (restart sphinx) : 0
Mon Aug  1 11:04:40 EDT 2016 : searchd restarted..
```

It seems like searchd take 2 to 3 minutes to restart, unlike it did a month ago (and nothing changed). And the exit code 0 means there was to error during the stopwait or the startup of searchd.

I can't seem to find what causes those binlogs to be created and don't know where to look anymore. Any idea what the problem might be? What log I didn't look at to find out more about the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a pertinent question, is WHY are you restarting searchd at all? It should never be needed in 'normal' operation. --rotate, should take care of loading indexs, which should be handled in such a way to as to avoid ANY downtime. Restarting searchd manually, will ALWAYS cause downtime, just that it may be a few seconds, so you dont realise it.

Comment: I wonder if its, because you restart so often, its creating a new binlog each time, so the delay is while it enumerates them all from disk. Then all empty hence no replay. Shutdown searchd gracefully. Delete all the empty binlog files. Start it up again.

Comment: @barryhunter indeed, it was useless to restart. I did not make the original script so I didn't even take into account that maybe restarting was useless. No downtime now, thanks !